# Set background of my application

Tags: objective-c, ios9

I have 3 views in my IOS app name WALLPAPER WORLD In Iphone. Details are as follows :

1st View: There are only buttons like HD, Cars, bikes,etc. When i click on HD button it fetch data from server (JSON PARSING) and i can get all the images in 2nd view

2nd view: I have a table control in which i can get all the images. When i click on specific image at that time another view is open and there i can see full image on 3rd view which i was clicked.

And now my question is HOW CAN I  SET THAT(Selected) IMAGE AT MY WALLPAPER SCREEN ?

Comment: If you want to do that so first you save your image into gallery and than set wallpaper from gallery.

Comment: Thanks for response but sir how can i save or download image which come from the server?

Comment: No Need to DOWN VOTE no one have answer of my question :):):)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**EDIT**

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(YOUR_SELETED_IMAGE, nil, nil, nil);
```

Hope this helps.